# Global variables with single precision in matlab

Tags: matlab, global-variables

Can I declare a global variable in matlab which is of type single?
From my knowledge, default global variables take the size as double

Comment: `global a; a = single(a);` http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html

Comment: @scmg for the sake of complete Q&A pairs, would you consider providing that as an answer?

Comment: @Schorsch yes sir, i updated the answer ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After declaring a global variable by `global myvar;`, you can convert it to [`single`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) type by:

```
myvar = single(myvar);
```

And as `single` is one of the [numeric types of Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html), you can also use [`cast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html) or [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

```
myvar = cast(myvar, 'single');
myvar = typecast(myvar, 'single');
```